# Trouble connecting to remote SQL Server 2005 with PHP using mssql

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've been struggling with this for a ridiculous amount of time and I'm not sure what to do. I'm using PHP 5.4 on a GoDaddy Linux shared hosting account with the mssql module enabled. The database I'm trying to reach is hosted elsewhere. I'm trying to connect via `mssql_connect`. I've tried

```
$con = mssql_connect('<ip address>', 'user', 'pass');
```

as well as

```
$con = mssql_connect('<ip address>\<instance name>', 'user', 'pass');
```

And the above two with port numbers. But I still get the "Unable to connect to server" error. I've made sure SQL Server is accepting outside connections and SQL Agent is running. I can't use `PDO` with `sqlserv` because of GoDaddy, mssql is the only module I'm able to use.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be wrong?

Comment: Use of MSSQL_ is deprecated and SQLSRV_ or PDO should be used. Will post an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SQLSRV](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlsrv.php) functions:

```
<?php
$serverName = "ipAddress\instanceName";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"pass" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Table_1 (id, data) VALUES (?, ?)";
$params = array(1, "some data");

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

**Note:** you don't need to inform the instance name in some cases. Try with IP address alone first.

Comment: Unfortunately, GoDaddy doesn't support SQLSRV or the PDO driver for SQL Server. I'm going to remove this question soon, though, because we believe it may be a firewall issue.

Comment: Could be. Check your PHP Version, from php.net:  "This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later. SQLSRV, an alternative extension for MS SQL connectivity is available from Microsoft: » http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx."